# What makes Firebug/Chrome console treat a custom object as an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, console, firebug

When I am developing in jQuery, I frequently find myself typing selectors into the Chrome/Firebug console and seeing what they give me.  They are always nicely formatted as if they were arrays:

[image: Chrome's console shows a jQuery selection as an array]

I am trying to work out what it is that makes the console treat an object as an array.  For instance, the following custom object is not treated as an array:

```
function ElementWrapper(id) {
    this[0] = document.getElementById(id);
}
```

[image: Chrome's console shows the object as a normal object]

If I then add a `length` property and a `splice` method, it magically works as an array, with any properties with integer keys treated as members of the arrays:

```
function ElementWrapper(id) {
    this[0] = document.getElementById(id);
    this.length = 1;
    this.splice = Array.prototype.splice;
}
```

[image: Chrome's console shows the object as if it was an array]

So essentially my question is: **what determines whether the console displays an object as an array**?  Is there any rationale to it, or is it a completely arbitrary "if an object has these properties, it must be an array?" If so, what are the decisive properties?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what Firebug's `isArray` method does: (from the [Firebug source](http://fbug.googlecode.com/svn/lite/branches/firebug1.4/build/firebug-lite-debug.js))

```
if (!obj)
    return false;
else if (isIE && !isFunction(obj) && typeof obj == "object" && isFinite(obj.length) && obj.nodeType != 8)
    return true;
else if (isFinite(obj.length) && isFunction(obj.splice))
    return true;
else if (isFinite(obj.length) && isFunction(obj.callee)) // arguments
    return true;
else if (instanceOf(obj, "HTMLCollection"))
    return true;
else if (instanceOf(obj, "NodeList"))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Of course, none of these checks ensures that the object is a true JavaScript array, but they do a reasonable job of guessing whether an object is a pseudo-array, which in turn gives you a convenient array-like representation for debugging.

Chrome may or may not use these same checks, and the new Web Console in Firefox 4 doesn't recognize anything other than true arrays as arrays.

Comment: So for a jquery selection result, which one is true?

Comment: I missed this the other day. Nice answer. +1

Comment: Chrome uses the same firebug detection:
// FireBug's array detection.
        if (isFinite(obj.length) && typeof obj.splice === "function")
            return "array";
        if (isFinite(obj.length) && typeof obj.callee === "function") // arguments.
            return "array";