# How does jQuery allow you to use [] on a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I had the following markup:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

And I use the following to retrieve them:

```
var divs = $('div');
```

How is it possible that I am able to retrieve the respective DOM element by using the `[]` syntax *and* also be able to call methods on the jQuery object such as `.first()`?

```
var div_one = divs[0];
```

I'm asking this question because it looks to me that `divs` is a jQuery **object**, not a true JavaScript `Array` object.

How does this work?

Comment: Sorry I'm writing here, I don't know another way to send a message to another user. Why did you deleted your answer to my yesterday's question? It was on the track of what I need to do

Comment: @TheDisintegrator Undeleted as you wish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numeric indices are just properties of the returned object. It's similar to doing this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[0] = 'foo';
alert(obj[0]);
```

Arrays and pseudo-array objects are almost identical - the only difference is that the `length` property of a true array is automatically managed by the JavaScript engine.

Comment: @Nathan: No it doesn't. It returns an object that has some Array methods prototyped into it. It is not an Array.

Comment: @Nathan How could it be an `Array` if I can invoke methods on it such as `.eq()` and `.first()`?

Comment: @Jacob: Those methods could have been prototyped into Array, but that's not what's happening in jQuery.

Comment: @Nathan Taylor: Aren't arrays objects in JavaScript? `var $divs = $('div'); $divs.test = 'foo'; $divs.test //returns 'foo'`

Comment: @patrick dw It'd make no sense to prototype them into `Array`.

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call( $() );` returns `[object Object]`

Comment: @patrickdw: I did not know this. I'm going to take another look at the sources now. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @Nathan Taylor: "both Arrays and Objects are typeof 'object'" -- however that doesn't make them the same. True arrays have an internal class of "Array" while regular objects have class "Object", and this is what makes arrays behave as arrays. You can check this by doing `Object.prototype.toString.call(some_object)`

Comment: From jQuery documentation: The jQuery object itself behaves much like an array; it has a length property and the elements in the object can be accessed by their numeric indices [0] to [length-1]. Note that a jQuery object is not actually a Javascript Array object, so it does not have all the methods of a true Array object such as join().

Comment: @Jacob: I'd tend to agree. Only point was that the ability to invoke `.eq()` and `.first()` doesn't mean it's *not* an Array. If you wanted an Array to be a default container for DOM elements, you could do this (but I'd advise against it). :o)

Comment: @patrickdw I spoke to the team in the jQuery IRC channel and they cleared it right up for me. A call to jQuery() returns a jQuery object which has had indexer properties applied to it dynamically. When the properties are called they return a call to jQuery().get() which returns the array of DOM elements contained in the jQuery object. Like you said, all of the Array methods on the jQuery object are simply prototyped onto it and operate on the internal array of DOM elements.

Comment: @Nathan: I hear what you're saying, but I personally don't like terms such as *"array...contained in the jQuery object"* and *"internal array"*. It implies that the jQuery object has an internal reference to a actual Array. [What it actually does](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5/src/core.js#L197) when `get()` is called is it constructs a new (actual) Array via `Array.prototype.slice`. You can do this with a regular object as long as the properties are numeric, and it has a `length` property as well. [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/8rgRM/1/)

Comment: if it doesn't reference an array, then how is it shown in the console like an array?

Comment: @Amjad Masad: The console can be easily fooled. If you create an object literal with a `length` property and a `splice` property that references any function, the console will assume you have an Array. Try this: `var myobj={length:0,splice:function(){}};`. If you do `console.log(myobj)` it will display an Array with no members even though it is clearly an object.

Comment: @Amjad Masad: This very same question was actually asked just a couple of days back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951054/what-makes-firebug-chrome-console-treat-a-custom-object-as-an-array

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with any object. It doesn't really have anything to do with it being an "Array-like" object.

```
var myObj = {};

myObj[0] = 'some value';

alert( myObj[0] );
```

---

Here's an example of creating an Array-like object:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8rgRM/

```
  // create constructor
function MyObj(){}

  // extend it with an Array method
MyObj.prototype.push = Array.prototype.push;

  // create an instance
var inst = new MyObj;

  // use the push method
inst.push( 'some value' );

  // the instance automatically has a length property that was updated
alert( inst.length );
```

It may be tempting to thing that  the length property will behave just as it will in an actual Array, but it doesn't.

For example, with an Array you can do `length = 0` to clear the content of the Array, but it won't work in an object like the one above.

In jQuery's source, [here is where Array.prototype.push](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5/src/core.js#L68) is referenced, and [here is where it is extended](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5/src/core.js#L288) into the jQuery prototype.

Answer (score 2):

This would clear things up a bit. Try it and play with it.

```
//used to produce pure classical inheritance
function clone(obj){
    function F(){};
    F.prototype=obj;
    return new F();
}
// Constructor function, used to instantiate a new object of myDivQuery Class
myDivQuery = function (){
    var div_list = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i=0; i < div_list.length; i++){
        this[i] = div_list[i];
    }
    this.length = div_list.length;
};
//myDivQuery inherits from Array class
myDivQuery.prototype = clone( new Array );
//add new methods to myDivQuery class, which is not added to the orginal Array class
myDivQuery.prototype.first = function (){
    return this[0];
}

myDivQuery.prototype.last = function (){
    return this[this.length - 1]
}
divs = new myDivQuery();
divs[0]; // first div on the page;
divs[1]; // the second div on the page ....
divs instanceof Array; //true
divs instanceof myDivQuery; //true
divs.first() === divs[0]; //true
divs.last(); //last div on page
Array.prototype.first; //undefined
divs.slice(1); //but still can use array methods
divs.reverse(); //another array method
```

this is how you sort of create a pseudo array, one huge remark is Arrays in javascript can't be sub classed, i.e. cannot create a sub array with the same array features, the main reason for that is the behavior of the length property in an array, which is hidden from the JS programmer, but there is many hacks and work-arounds for doing that, to learn more read this brilliant article by kangax.  http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can access properties of objects using the same syntax used for array-index notation:

```
var o = {'foo':'bar'},
  fooVar = 'bar';

//these all alert 'bar'
alert(o.foo);
alert(o['foo']);
alert(o[fooVar]);
```

However, you can only use the dot notation for valid names. `o[0]` works, but `o.0` does not.

jQuery returns a `jQuery.init` object that contains a number of properties (i.e. `length`), as well as a map of the `dom elements` or other raw javascript objects matched by the selector, listed from `0` to `n`.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a selector (`$("div")` in the start post) returns a result [with the type Jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#jQuery)

To quote from the jquery page:

> The jQuery object itself behaves much
>   like an array; it has a length
>   property and the elements in the
>   object can be accessed by their
>   numeric indices [0] to [length-1].
>   Note that a jQuery object is not
>   actually a Javascript Array object, so
>   it does not have all the methods of a
>   true Array object such as join().