# Why does jQuery.fn display [] in the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand how jQuery is coded.

They have an object:

```
jQuery.fn = {
     //key value pairs
}
```

But if I type `jQuery.fn` in the browser console, it just returns `[]` and not the object itself. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951054/what-makes-firebug-chrome-console-treat-a-custom-object-as-an-array

Comment: If you want to see how it works, feel free to dig through the uncompressed [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js).

Comment: Interesting. I just typed `jQuery.isPlainObject(jQuery.fn)` into the Chrome Console and it returned true, but `jQuery.isArray(jQuery.fn)` returns false despite `jQuery.fn` being represented as `[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jQuery.fn` simply meets the requirements of being [array-like for the developer consoles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951054/what-makes-firebug-chrome-console-treat-a-custom-object-as-an-array). It's not actually an `Array` instance*, but it has an interface that affords being treated as an array.

<sub>*If `jQuery.fn` were *actually* an array, `jQuery.fn instanceof Array` would evaluate to `true`; it doesn't. It *does* copy some of the `Array.prototype` methods though.</sub>

---

If you want to check if an object is actually an `Array`, there are two means, the simplest is `obj instanceof Array`, however this will be true for objects that inherit from `Array`. If you want to check that an object is an Array, but need to exclude objects that inherit from `Array` you should use:

```
function isArray(arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
}
```

Example:

```
var a, b;
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype = [];
a = new Foo();
b = [];
a instanceof Array; //true
b instanceof Array; //true
isArray(a);         //false
isArray(b);         //true
```

Comment: OK. Now how can I view the methods inside the object if the console shows it as array

Comment: got it myself. I just deleted the slice and length properties ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try typing only jQuery in your console, jQuery.fn is it's prototype