# Setting prototype property of Javascript function to custom object

Tags: javascript, prototype

Can someone explain why it is that these all return a `Baz` object:

```
function Baz(){};
new Baz();
Baz.prototype = new String();
new Baz();
Baz.prototype = new RegExp();
new Baz();
```

But the following gives me an array object?

```
Baz.prototype = new Array();
new Baz();
```

Comment: Please test again with `new Baz() instanceof Baz`. They should all return true, even the array one. What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: It doesn't give you an Array object. It just displays that way in your developer console because your object now inherits a `splice()` function and a `.length`. Don't rely exclusively on console display to determine what an object is.

Comment: for exmaple: `foo={splice:function(){},length:0}` This will look like an Array in Chrome's console, but it clearly isn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What makes Firebug/Chrome console treat a custom object as an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951054/what-makes-firebug-chrome-console-treat-a-custom-object-as-an-array)

Comment: Where do you "*return*" anything in that code? What are you doing that lets you think anything "*gives you*" some type of object?

Comment: I used the Chrome console